# How can I play video from YouTube channel in Decentraland?

Tags: youtube, augmented-reality, virtual, virtual-reality

There is sample code to play video in Decentraland. [This link](https://docs.decentraland.org/development-guide/video-playing/)
However, I want to play video from a playlist in YouTube channel. Is there any sample code you can reefer me?

Comment: Add the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot directly access any Youtube videos due to a CORS policy set on their side. This is not an issue with Decentraland itself, but rather with Youtube and other content providers that have a similar CORS policy.

Youtube and Twitch (for example) have their own javascript players that not only display ads but also gather information about the viewer. Seeing as this is the basis of their income, they do not want people bypassing this and just viewing the video for "free".

You may notice that youtube videos work in CryptoVoxel for some reason. This is due to some trickery that the game is doing, where it is loading in the html/js and placing the video on-top of the game itself. (At least that is what I've heard)

In the meantime I strongly suggest you look into hosting your videos on another platform like Vimeo. You can directly access the video files if you pay for their service. Alternatively, you can host your videos on an Antmedia server through a cloud hosting service like Digital Ocean. Both of these are great options.